Use regex in C# to replace single and double quotation marks with smart quotation marks
I am creating a text heavy game and the text-based content currently has non-smart (", ') quotation marks but we want there to be smart (“, ”, ‘, ’) quotation marks.
I had programmed a loop to do this conversion during runtime but a regex approach could be far more suitable than my hefty loop.
I've found it quite difficult to generate any good regular expressions (given a general lack of skill in the regex department).
An example conversion would be:
"TEXT 'TEXT "'TEXT' TEXT"' TEXT." "TEXT TEX'T
Becomes:
“TEXT ‘TEXT “‘TEXT’ TEXT”’ TEXT.” “TEXT TEX'T
How should I go about creating code for this conversion?
Here is my updated version of the loop I've created. Perhaps this is more efficient than a regex solution would be.
        // Applying smart quotations
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(richText);

        bool smartQuotation = true;
        for(int i = 0; i < builder.Length; i++)
        {
            if (smartQuotation)
            {
                if (builder[i] == '\'')
                {
                    builder[i] = '‘';
                }
                else if (builder[i] == '\"')
                {
                    builder[i] = '“';
                }
                else if (!char.IsPunctuation(builder[i]))
                {
                    smartQuotation = false;
                }
            }
            else if (builder[i] == ' ')
            {
                smartQuotation = true;
            }
        }

        smartQuotation = true;
        for (int i = builder.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        { 
            if (smartQuotation)
            {
                if (builder[i] == '\'')
                {
                    builder[i] = '’';
                }
                else if (builder[i] == '\"')
                {
                    builder[i] = '”';
                }
                else if (!char.IsPunctuation(builder[i]))
                {
                    smartQuotation = false;
                }
            } 
            else if (builder[i] == ' ')
            {
                smartQuotation = true;
            }
        }

        return builder.ToString(); 


What should happen if an input text has unbalanced quotes?

Must you use regex?

I'd be curious to see your "hefty loop", since it seems more trivial and performant to handle this task with a loop, than with the sledgehammer that is regex.

Do you have any nested quotations? Simply pairing of sequential marks seem fairly easy, and I imagine it would cover most use cases.

Balancing groups may help. But it is very difficult. I would manually write a parser on a finite state machine.

As in the example above, I'm not concerned about if the quotes are unbalanced. Basically, if they have a space or start of string to their left, after any abritary amount of punctuation, they should be a left smart quotation. Alternatively, if they have a space or end of string to their right after any arbitrary number of punctuation marks, they should be a right smart quotation mark.
If a loop would likely be much more performant, I'll continue with my current solution.

I've shown my "hefty loop" on the original post and it is not so hefty as it was previously.

In your example, you also replace the last opening double quotes that has no closing quotes. You want to replace that as well?

No, as I've said above, I am not concerned about whether they are balanced and this should not be checked for, which heavily simplifies the problem.

In general, you can't do this using a regex.
Your example
"TEXT 'TEXT "'TEXT' TEXT"' TEXT." "TEXT TEX'T has nested quotes of arbitrary nesting depth and regexes, lacking memory, can't solve such problems (it's somewhat analogous to the parentheses balancing problem).

I think the nesting isn't necessarily a problem, because balanced quotes are not a requirement and are not checked for in the example above, only the relation between the quotation marks and the closest (through other punctuation marks) spaces/string start or end ought to be considered I believe.
I do think perhaps this isn't the best place for regex so I'll move forward with my custom solution which may be more performant. Thank you for the input.

There is no good solution to using a Regex replace directly, because not only do we want to match and substitute groups, we want multiple alternative groups interchangeably and possibly inter-woven.
A reasonable, readable implementation can use regex to search for the character indices which are then replaced in a StringBuilder:
Matching balanced groups (open and closing quotes in a group):
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

var t = @"aa""AAA 'BBB ""'CCC' DDD""' EEE."" ""FFF GGG'zz";

void ReplaceGroup(StringBuilder sb, char c, char replace1, char replace2)
{
    var matches = Regex.Matches(t, @$"({c}.*?{c})");
    var allCaptures = matches.SelectMany(x => x.Captures);
    foreach (var capture in allCaptures)
    {
        // for debug: Console.WriteLine($"capture {capture}");
        sb[capture.Index] = replace1;
        sb[capture.Index + capture.Length - 1] = replace2;
    }
}

var sb = new StringBuilder(t);
ReplaceGroup(sb, '"', '“', '”');
ReplaceGroup(sb, '\'', '‘', '’');
var r = sb.ToString();

// r has value: "aa“AAA ‘BBB ”’CCC‘ DDD“’ EEE.” "FFF GGG'zz"

Because we want to match opening and closing quotation characters we can't use a single group match.
The ? after the * quantifier on .*? is used to switch from a greedy to a non-greedy search, so that the narrowest possible match is used. See Quantifiers in Regular Expressions.
If it should not be restricted to balanced groups (replace opening quotation character only if closing exists) then the regex search is effectively a simple character search and an index loop or alternatively, repeated Array.FindIndex calls can be used instead to the same effect and at better readability and performance.

Fortunately, I am not concerned with balanced groups. After consideration, I think I'll go ahead with the current loop I outlined above in the question, which achieves the result with 2 complete loops and is likely nearly as fast as I'll be able to get it.

Many of the answers have assumed I needed balanced quotes, though that's a large over-complication of the requirements and the example I gave had shown that it was not a requirement.
From my current understanding, the loop I generated and have given in the original post is already something similar to the fastest version of the algorithm, so I'll move forward with that solution.
Thanks for your responses.
